# query string, changes required in urls.py and view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

A basic django question, but stumping me.

I have an existing view for an endpoint. 
http://localhost:8001/v1/subject - which returns all subjects from the subject model.

I want to serve a new endpoint...
http://localhost:8001/v1/subject?owner_ids=60,61,62

What would be the changes required in the "urls.py" definition and

'''
def query_set
'''
method in views/subject.py,

I have added the method but it's not working as intended.

Here's the urls.py definition, any changes required to accommodate a query string?

```
router.register(r'subjects', views.SubjectsViewSet)
```

Should I do something like this?

```
    url(r'^v1/subjects/',
        views.SubjectViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}))
```

Also, here's my views/subjects.py file...the logic in def get_queryset  may work, but how do I wire the urls.py entry so that the querystring  localhost:8001/v1/subjects?owner_ids=60,61,62 is served together with the regular localhost:8001/v1/subjects ?

```
class SubjectViewSet(Subject.get_viewset()):
    pagination_class = SubjectPagination

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
                owner_id_list = 
        self.request.GET['owner_ids'].split(',')
        owner_id_list_integer = []
        for i in owner_id_list:
            owner_id_list_integer.append(int(i))
        queryset = Subject.objects.all()

        if owner_id_list is None:
            return None
        else:
            return queryset.filter(organization__in=owner_id_list)

SubjectUserRoleViewSet = Subject.get_by_user_role_viewset(
    SubjectViewSet, GroupRoleMap, Role)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this way.

```py
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        splited = self.request.GET['owner_ids'].split(',')
        filtered_nums = list(filter(None, splited))
        try:
            get_nums = list(map(int, filtered_nums))
        except ValueError as exc:
            return Subject.objects.none()
        else:
            return Subject.objects.filter(organization__in=get_nums)
```

I hope, I do not have a mistake.

Comment: This may work (yet to try) but how do I serve two end points...the first one regular v1/subjects, the second one with a query string vi/subjects?owner_ids=1,2,3

Comment: ```if self.request.GET['owner_ids']:
    # implement logic when you have query string vi/subjects?owner_ids=1,2,3
    return qs1
# implement logic when you do not have a query string vi/subjects
return qs2```

Comment: Just check ```query_params```, if it exists return something if does not exists implement other logic.